# Storing values in eax in assembly

Tags: assembly

```
extern printf                ; the C function, to be called

SECTION .data                ; Data section, initialized variables
a: dd 5                      ; int a=5;
fmt: db "a=%d, eax=%d",10,0  ; The printf format, "\n",'0'

SECTION .text                ; Code section.

global main                  ; the standard gcc entry point
main:                        ; the program label for the entry point

   push ebp                  ; calling convention
   mov ebp, esp

   mov eax, [a]              ; put a from store into register
   add eax, 2                ; a+2
   push eax                  ; value of a+2
   push dword [a]            ; value of variable a
   push dword fmt            ; address of ctrl string
   call printf               ; Call C function
   add  esp, 12              ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes

   mov esp, ebp              ; returning convention
   pop ebp                   ; same as "leave" op

   mov eax,0                 ;  normal (no error) return value
   ret                       ; return
```

I'm getting a bit confused. I know that `dd` declares a 4 byte value and stores 5 in it.

1) Then `mov eax, [a]` stores it in eax register. But isn't AX only a 2 byte register. How can it store a 4 byte value?

2) `fmt: db "a=%d, eax=%d",10,0` I know fmt is a location name and db declares a byte, but then what does the rest of the code do?

Comment: E stands for Extended. EAX stores 32 bits.

Comment: Regarding #2, I recommend you look up information on how the printf function works with format strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

terminology: reading from memory (`add eax, [a]`) is a "load".  Writing to memory is a "store" (`mov [a], eax`).

A `dd` directive doesn't "store" in that sense, though.  The data is already there when your program starts.  Use a word like "puts" or "places" to avoid using "store", which has a technical meaning in this context.

---

1. `eax` is 4B.  `ax` is the low 2 bytes of `eax`, just like `al` is the low byte of `ax`.  See the links at the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki.  I think wikipedia's x86 article has a register diagram showing the names of the register subsets.  (`rdi / edi / di / dil` (`rdi/dil` only available in 64bit mode), `EFLAGS`, etc.)
2. `"string", 10, 0` is a string with a newline and a terminating zero byte.

---

```
   push ebp                  ; calling convention
   mov ebp, esp
```

Making stack frames is *not* part of the "calling convention".  gcc defaults to `-fomit-frame-pointer` these days, because modern debug-info formats allow stack backtraces for debugging and exception-handling even without it.  Making stack frames is an optional part of the ABI, but not strictly what you'd call part of the "calling convention".  The meaning of that term is limited to where functions find their args, and how they return them, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: is the `, 10, 0` part necessary or is it just there to make the printf output look nice?

Comment: @Everythingsucks:  The 10 is necessary if you want a linefeed.  Leave out the `\n` in a Hello World program and see for yourself.  The `0` is absolutely necessary, of course.  The end of a C string is marked only by the zero-byte; there's no length stored anywhere else for printf to know where the string ends.